# Regex returning whole string instead of just the capture group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

trying to just get the value, but the regex is returning BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"xxxxx.
  server response is

> {"data":[{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"8199.91"},{"base":"BCH","currency":"USD","amount":"1012.22"},{"base":"ETH","currency":"USD","amount":"825.94"},{"base":"LTC","currency":"USD","amount":"150.11"}]}

how can i only use the value in the capture group?

```
                public async void UpdateValue()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.coinbase.com/api/v2/prices/USD/spot?");
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JToken BTC = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
                string btcV = BTC.ToString();
                Regex regex = new Regex("BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^\"]*)");
                Match match = regex.Match(btcV);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = match.Value;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at `Match.Captures` && `Match.Groups`

Comment: Looks like JSON data, you sure you want to use REGEX and not a JSON parser?

Comment: Don't use Regex for JSON.  Use JSON.NET and parse the json into an object

Comment: I've edited it, somewhere is messed up. I've never used json so i'm not sure what i'm doing.

Comment: He's already using JSON.NET or he wouldn't have `JToken` in his code? The question is why he is converting from the `string responseBody` to a `JToken` and then back to a `string` only to regex extract from it. What's the point of that code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

- `match.Groups[0]` is the whole match which is the same as `match.value` in your case.
- `match.Groups[1]` is the first capture group specified by `(` and `)` in the pattern. This comes after the whole match in group `0`.
- `match.Groups[2...]` is the second group and so on ...

Have you checked the other groups?

Comment: Thank you so much! match.Groups[1].ToString(); works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comment, use JSON.NET library.

It would be straight forward like:

```
List<ClassA> objects= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClassA>>(json);
```

Find more details https://www.newtonsoft.com/json